# Google Spreadsheet - Use IF Else condition in SUMPRODUCT formula

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, spreadsheet, array-formulas

I have a Google Sheet that has quiz entries. Each correct answer adds points and points will be deducted for wrong answer.

Here I use `ARRAYFORMULA(SUMPRODUCT)` formula to calculate points. The formula works fine to add points if answer is correct, but I want to deduct points for each wrong answer as an else condition.

**My Spreadsheet**

[image: Quiz Answer/Point]

In above sheet, I want to deduct -5 point from `Q3` for the wrong answer in `N3` and calculate the points in `O3`.
How can I achieve this? How can I add `if, else` condition to this formula?

Comment: Can a name score less than 0? Can George's score be -15?

Comment: Yes. That is what exactly needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O3:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(MMULT(IF(L3:N5=L1:N1,TRANSPOSE(P3:P5),TRANSPOSE(Q3:Q5)),TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(L1:N1))^0))
```

- IF to get correct score
- MMULT to add corresponding scores

Answer (score 0):

If what you have is working for you, just add another set of sumproduct conditions to the formula already there

```
=... + ARRAYFORMULA(SUMPRODUCT((L3<>L1)*Q3 + ...)))
```

Answer (score 0):

In an unused column to the right, put this formula into the third row.

```
=max(0, arrayformula(SUM(if(L3:N3=L$1:N$1, P3, Q3))))
'if Georges score can be negative then,
=arrayformula(SUM(if(L3:N3=L$1:N$1, P3, Q3)))
```

Double click the 'fill handle' (tiny square in the bottom-right of the selected cell) to fill down.

[image]